# how to lookup a key word in multiple sentences i.e. array and then return a number that is next to the original key word list of lookup words

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Hello Stack Overflow community please help me with the problem below

how to lookup a key word in multiple sentences i.e., array and then return a number that is next to the original key word
list of lookup words.

we have 3 arrays

List of what words to Find
List of sentences to find the original word
and list of numbers that are related to the original searched word.

The number is to be returned to the same row as the original sentance that coresponds to the original
searched word.

Regards Troy

[image]

Variour attems to get some sort of result.

=INDEX(A2:A12,MATCH(D2:A12,D2:D12,))

=INDEX(list,SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(list,A2))*ROW($1:$3)))

=IF($D2="","",(INDEX({B2:B12,""},MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({D2:D12"," ",""},D2)),0))))

=INDEX(B2:B12,MATCH(1,(A2:A12=D2)*(D2:D12=D2),0))

=VLOOKUP(B2,A2:A12,2,0)

=INDEX(B2:B12,MATCH(D2,A2:A12,))

Comment: Which one is your desired result?

Comment: Use [`XLOOKUP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) with wildcard search

Comment: yes i have tried vlookup, but i cound not get vlookup to read a sentence... please see the picture att in the body of the question

Comment: Hello @Harun24hr in the picture provided i have shown the output section in red as what it should look like, i did this manually, i have shown the correct results in the pictured in column listed as number 4. but can't get the any formula to do this for me.

Comment: as @chrisneilsen sir has said, `XLOOKUP()` should work for you. So that said the formula will be `=XLOOKUP(1,SEARCH(D$2:D$12,A2),F$2:F$12,"")` try this is you have access to `XLOOKUP()` function

Comment: Or, use `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` with `ISNUMBER()` & `SEARCH()` like this `=INDEX($F$2:$F$11,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$11,A2)),0))`

Comment: hello @Mayukh Bhattacharya, the formula is not searching the A2:A12 array where the sentence is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try in this way,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D2,$A$2:$A$11)),0))
```

---

If you have access to MS365, then use `XLOOKUP()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,$A$2:$A$11)),$B$2:$B$11,"")
```

---

You can also use a `LOOKUP()` Function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH(D2,$A$2:$A$11),$B$2:$B$11)
```

---

Much better way is using WildCard With XLOOKUP() function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=XLOOKUP("*"&D2&"*",$A$2:$A$11,$B$2:$B$11,"",2)
```

---

With `VLOOKUP()` & wildcard as well,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&D2&"*",$A$2:$B$11,2,0)
```

Comment: thank you for that but the formula needs to be in F2 to F12.  as that is where the results are

Comment: @Troy understood, updating now, you need the other way round

Comment: woohooo you got it :) @Mayukh Bhattacharya    both options now working =INDEX($B$3:$B$12,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D3,$A$3:$A$12)),0))      =XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D3,$A$3:$A$12)),$B$3:$B$12,"")

Comment: @Troy I have updated few, found we missed the wild card use, it should work with that as well